# CSS and JS not loading after transferring site

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I initially developed my app on IIS and I am now moving back to Apache.

I have copied the whole application directory onto a new Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server. I am running my app as a virtual directory so that I can have multiple sites.

I have deleted the web.config files and updated the .htaccess files and I have the home.ctp page loading.  I have tried to load one of my index views and it starts loading the page but the CSS and Javascript don't load.

In the webroot/index.php I found and updated the "CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH" which was hard coded to the Windows drive.

I have my app under /usr/share/SRP and I have a SRP.conf to give me a url of http://server.com/SRP/

```
Alias /SRP /usr/share/SRP

<Directory /usr/share/SRP>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
</Directory>
```

When I try to access another page, e.g. http://server.com/SRP/users, the page loads without the CSS and Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SRP/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
```

In this case the javascript doesn't load (gets a 404).

```
<img src="/SRP/img/cake.power.gif" alt="Systems Management Request Portal" border="0" />
```

It seesm strange to me that the cake gif does load.  So does DebugKit and toolbar.

I think this a problem with mod_rewrite or WEBROOT_DIR.

Comment: Check where you `script` and `img` tags really point to in the rendered HTML page.

Comment: Check you have all three .htaccess files in root, app and webroot directory of your cakephp project. if yes check apache mod-rewrite modules is installed and loaded. Most of the times .htaccess files are not transferred while moving code.

Comment: I had to copy the js, css and img files from SRP/app/webroot to SRP/webroot. Is that because I changed from IIS to Apache or is it something to do with url rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the js, css and img files from SRP/app/webroot to SRP/webroot.  I don't understand why changing web servers caused this change.